# Sort direction in url Spring Pageable

Tags: spring-mvc, pagination, spring-data, thymeleaf

I have a controller with following method. I can add a property 'sort' to my form and it will automatically use that property to sort. Now I'm trying to add the sort direction to it, but I can't seem to find the correct request param to add to my form.

```
public String overview(Criteria criteria, @PageableDefault(sort = "name") Pageable page, Model model)
```

This is my form:

```
<form action="">
<div>
    <label for="sort">Sort by</label>

    <select name="sort" id="sort">
        <option value="name" selected>Name</option>
        <option value="description">Description</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="ascending">
        <input name="order" id="ascending" type="radio" value="ASC" />
        <div>Ascending</div>
    </label>
    <label for="descending">
        <input name="order" id="descending" type="radio" value="DESC" />
        <div>Descending</div>
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</div>
</form>
```

The url looks like this:

```
/overview?sort=name&order=DESC
```

I've tried some other parameter names than order, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: can you try with name="sort" to `sort_var` or `sort_param`?

Comment: the sort works, the direction doesn't

Answer (score 1):

The direction should be appended to the `sort` query parameter such that it will look like this

```
/overview?sort=name,DESC
```

Just repeat for multiple sort fields like

```
/overview?sort=name,DESC&sort=description,ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend your controller method like this:

```
public String overview(Criteria criteria, @PageableDefault(sort = "name", final @RequestParam(value = "order", defaultValue = "ASC") String order, Pageable page, Model model) {
    // process the order argument here
}
```

Now you can process the argument "order".